# How to present data by DOM not by table

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom

I have a doubt in the application I'm creating, I'm working with an Oracle database, and I'm bringing the information from the database and presenting it on the screen through a table, but I wanted to try to work separately with this data, for example creating a paragraph and display a value.

I was only able to present the data through a table, is there another way? Thanks a lot if anyone can help me with this.

I accept all tips to improve the code.

My **Index.html** page

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Apontamentos da Produção</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="screen" />

</head>

<body>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">

  <div id="data"></div>

  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="texto"> PAINEL-1 | APONTAMENTOS DA PRODUÇÃO</div>
      <div class="clock"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
  </div>

  <br>

  <!-- Tabela principal, apresentando os apontamentos -->
  <table id="table" class="tablePrincipal">
    <tr class="trPrincipal">
      <th class="th2" style="width: 11%;">Data</th>
      <th class="th2" style="width: 8%; ">Hora</th>
      <th class="th2" style="width: 5%;">Orig.</th>
      <th class="th2" style="width: 8%;">O.P.</th>
      <th class="th2" style="width: 10%;">Produto</th>
      <th class="th2" style="width: 8%;">Deriv.</th>
      <th class="th2" style="width: 9%;">Peso (TN)</th>
      <th class="th2" style="width: 7%;">Refugo (TN)</th>
      <th class="th2" style="width: 13%;">Lote</th>
      <th class="th2" style="width: 60%;;">Operador</th>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <br>

</body>

<script>

// Tabela de apontamentos. Listagem.

  // Aqui é onde é feito o push de informações, chamando pelo caminho e colocando o ID da tabela que ele vai levar as informações

  window.onload = function () {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/teste')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        var table = document.getElementById('table');

        // Primeiro define a variavel, e coloca o comando para inserir uma linha, é tudo organizado por rows
        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
          var row = table.insertRow(i + 1);
          var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
          var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
          var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
          var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
          var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
          var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
          var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
          var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
          var cell9 = row.insertCell(8);
          var cell10 = row.insertCell(9);

          // Queria trabalhar com os dados separadamente, tentar criar um <p> e colocar um dado para apresentar.

        // Queria tentar fazer um calculo com essa variável, mas não funciona assim
          var cell11 = cell7 * 2;

          // Aqui chama a variavel e coloca a linha na tabela
          cell1.innerHTML = data[i][0];
          cell2.innerHTML = data[i][1];
          cell3.innerHTML = data[i][2];
          cell4.innerHTML = data[i][3];
          cell5.innerHTML = data[i][4];
          cell6.innerHTML = data[i][5];
          cell7.innerHTML = data[i][6];
          cell8.innerHTML = data[i][7];
          cell9.innerHTML = data[i][8];
          cell10.innerHTML = data[i][9];
        
        
        }}
      )}
      
</script>

</html>
```

This is my **Index.js**, in it I'm doing the select and sending the data

```
const express = require('express');
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const app = express();
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
const http = require('http');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');



// Connection details for the Oracle database
const connectionString = '';
const user = '';
const password = '';

// Connect to the database
app.get('/teste', (req, res) => {

  // within the endpoint, query the database
  oracledb.getConnection(
    {
      connectionString: connectionString,
      user: user,
      password: password
    },
    function teste(err, connection) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        return;
      }
      console.log('Conexão deu certo!');

      const query = 'SELECT DATREA,HORREA,CODORI,NUMORP,CODPRO,CODDER,QTDRE1,QTDRFG,CODLOT,OPERADOR from USU_VPROEXT ORDER BY DATREA DESC, HORREA DESC';
      connection.execute(query, [], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
          return;
        }
        console.log('Banco de Dados Atualizado');
        console.log();

        // return the results to the user
        res.json(result.rows);
      });
    });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is listening on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: does that code work? if the answer is yes, you already know how the data is structured.. it looks like an array of arrays.. where the first layer are the rows and second layer the columns. What's exactly the problem you are encountering? if you need to transform data differently to prepare the content of a paragraph you could for example make one paragraph per row joining the columns like `const target = document.getElementById('target'); data.forEach( row => { const p = document.createElement('p'); p.textContent = row.join[' ']; target.append(p); });`

Comment: The code works, it was secured over arrays, which are data from the oracle database. But I can only present this data through tables, my problem is the following. I wanted to structure this data, for example, I wanted to get the result of the row1 variable and put it to be presented in a <p>. I wanted to understand how to work with the results separately

Answer (score 0):

### Assumptions:

Since the scenario cannot be exactly reproduced I will focus on the client side only taking for granted that your backend endpoint will correctly return an array like: `data[iRow][iColumn]`

Such assumption came from lines like this `cell1.innerHTML = data[i][0];`

### data example statically defined:

I'm not perfectly sure if data is just an array of array or there's some way to address the columns value by column name somehow. Anyway here we'll stick with the plain array paradigm since it seemed to work by your own words.

Here we define a `data` array with 2 rows having 10 columns each:

```
//the array you are supposed to receive from your ajax call
const data = [
  //first row of cells
  [
    'rowX_cell(01)',
    'rowX_cell(02)',
    'rowX_cell(03)',
    'rowX_cell(04)',
    'rowX_cell(05)',
    'rowX_cell(06)',
    'rowX_cell(07)',
    'rowX_cell(08)',
    'rowX_cell(09)',
    'rowX_cell(10)',
  ],
  //second row of cells
  [
    'rowY_cell(01)',
    'rowY_cell(02)',
    'rowY_cell(03)',
    'rowY_cell(04)',
    'rowY_cell(05)',
    'rowY_cell(06)',
    'rowY_cell(07)',
    'rowY_cell(08)',
    'rowY_cell(09)',
    'rowY_cell(10)',
  ],
]
```

### Defining columns name and order:

I can also say the order of columns fetched from DB since the SQL query was shown and that's the ordered list:

`DATREA,HORREA,CODORI,NUMORP,CODPRO,CODDER,QTDRE1,QTDRFG,CODLOT,OPERADOR`

That we are defining in js as an array of strings like this:

```
//ordered list of columns in the same order as the cols in data are supposed to be
const columnNames = ['DATREA','HORREA','CODORI','NUMORP','CODPRO','CODDER','QTDRE1','QTDRFG','CODLOT','OPERADOR'];
```

### Transform row array to object:

Transforming rows `data` to an array of objects having as properties the row columns named as the list of columns shown before:

```
function getRowObject(row){
  const rowObject = {};
  //for each col in columnNames
  columnNames.forEach((col, i)=>{
    //set the prop of rowObject named as col = the value at the i position in row
    rowObject[col] = row[i]; 
  });  
  return rowObject;
}
```

that for the first row of data (`data[0]`) would return an object like this:

```
{
  "DATREA": "rowX_cell(01)",
  "HORREA": "rowX_cell(02)",
  "CODORI": "rowX_cell(03)",
  "NUMORP": "rowX_cell(04)",
  "CODPRO": "rowX_cell(05)",
  "CODDER": "rowX_cell(06)",
  "QTDRE1": "rowX_cell(07)",
  "QTDRFG": "rowX_cell(08)",
  "CODLOT": "rowX_cell(09)",
  "OPERADOR": "rowX_cell(10)"
}
```

### How to show that data in the document?

You have infinite ways depending on what's exactly the goal. Actually you didn't need to transform the array to object to begin with, but it made it easier to access its columns by name instead of using a index number.

Anyway if for example you needed to show each row as the content of an individual paragraph having as content the concatenation of all its columns data:

```
function appendRowsAsParagraphsInTarget(target, rowObjects){
  //you can loop through all the rows and print them on screen
  rowObjects.forEach( row => {
    //here we are converting the row object back to a list of values
    values = columnNames.map( columnName => row[columnName] );
    //here to a single string where values are separated by ', ' and wrapped in []
    values = values.map( value => `[${value}]`);
    values = values.join(', ');  
  
    //append the newly created p in target
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    p.textContent = values;
    target.append(p);
  });
}
```

### Demo:

Here's a live demo of what said so far:

```js
//the array you are supposed to receive from your ajax call
const data = [
  //first row of cells
  [
    'rowX_cell(01)',
    'rowX_cell(02)',
    'rowX_cell(03)',
    'rowX_cell(04)',
    'rowX_cell(05)',
    'rowX_cell(06)',
    'rowX_cell(07)',
    'rowX_cell(08)',
    'rowX_cell(09)',
    'rowX_cell(10)',
  ],
  //second row of cells
  [
    'rowY_cell(01)',
    'rowY_cell(02)',
    'rowY_cell(03)',
    'rowY_cell(04)',
    'rowY_cell(05)',
    'rowY_cell(06)',
    'rowY_cell(07)',
    'rowY_cell(08)',
    'rowY_cell(09)',
    'rowY_cell(10)',
  ],
]

//ordered list of columns in the same order as the cols in data are supposed to be
const columnNames = ['DATREA','HORREA','CODORI','NUMORP','CODPRO','CODDER','QTDRE1','QTDRFG','CODLOT','OPERADOR'];

//transforming the original array of rows as array of objects where each one as col data as properties
const rowObjects = data.map( row => getRowObject(row) );

console.log(rowObjects);

//appending the rowObjects as p paragraph to #output_rows
const target = document.getElementById('output_rows');
appendRowsAsParagraphsInTarget(target, rowObjects);

function appendRowsAsParagraphsInTarget(target, rowObjects){
  //you can loop through all the rows and print them on screen
  rowObjects.forEach( row => {
    //here we are converting the row object back to a list of values
    values = columnNames.map( columnName => row[columnName] );
    //here to a single string where values are separated by ', ' and wrapped in []
    values = values.map( value => `[${value}]`);
    values = values.join(', ');  
  
    //append the newly created p in target
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    p.textContent = values;
    target.append(p);
  });
}

function getRowObject(row){
  const rowObject = {};
  //for each col in columnNames
  columnNames.forEach((col, i)=>{
    //set the prop of rowObject named as col = the value at the i position in row
    rowObject[col] = row[i]; 
  });  
  return rowObject;
}
```

```css
.label{
  font-weight: bold;
}

#output_rows{
}

#output_rows > p{
  border: solid 1px lightgray;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<p class="label">Showing all the table rows as p elements</p>

<div id="output_rows"></div>
```